# Safari on iOS Mobile hangs the page when submitting form from https to http

Tags: forms, https, safari, mobile-safari, safari-web-inspector

I am working on a project where I need to submit the form on HTTPS page to HTTP, during this process I receive a warning saying `Form Insecure are you sure you want to submit?` then if I submit it hangs forever. This flow is working on Mac Safari and all other browser on desktop as well as mobile.
Strange thing is on iOS it works on captive portal browser but not on safari. I cannot to the form posting to HTTPS because I need to make a ajax call on HTTP page to the Hotspot which return the client status. 
Firstly the warning itself should not appear because it doesn't on any other browser even if it does then the page should not hang.

Comment: Just started to have this same issue today. Would love to find an answer as well.

Comment: @tvirelli the solution to this problem is either move to complete `https` or `http`. But do note this issue has arised in latest iOS version it will not cause any issue before 10.3 iOS version.